# How the quality of clusters made in SPSS can be evaluated?

Tags: statistics, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, spss, clickstream

How the quality of clusters made in SPSS with the method "Two-step clustering" can be evaluated? Which test should be applied to be sure that the quality is good.

Comment: I think this is question for cross validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's SPSS... don't ask programmers, they don't use SPSS.